# Pivot table changing the source name after updating data source

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have an Excel with several pivot tables that I update monthly with data from another file. From the pivot table I pulled values to another tab using VLOOKUPS to the pivot tables. All pivot tables have the same data source and all of them with the exception of one pivot is not updating properly.

This is how it used to look whenever I refreshed the data to for the pivot monthly:

[image]

But for the last two months when I refresh the data it merges the grouping with the field I am pulling from the source data:
[image]

This is an inconvenient because since it changes the Source Name for the Pivot Fields, my formulas are no longer working. I even tried using the new name from the Source Name, but since Excel replaced the actual Field Value from the Data Source from "Budget Finalized Date" to "Months (Budget Finalized Data)" when the formulas are looking into the pivot table they are not finding a match for the Source Name because the name of the actual Field in the Source Data is "Budget Finalized Date" not "Months (Budget Finalized Data)". Since the data is coming from another excel that I do not manage I am not allow to change the name.
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]